# Remove iOS accessorytype of all non selected items

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have a listview showing contacts from my component

```
<ListView [items]="filteredContacts" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)" class="list-group" (itemLoading)="onItemLoading($event)">
```

I also have an accessory on the current selected contact however when I tap on a different row I would like to remove the accessory from the active row but not sure how.

```
onItemLoading(args: ItemEventData) {
   if(this.filteredContacts[args.index]['id'] == this.rules[0]['id']) {
     if (args.ios) {
         args.ios.accessoryType = 3;
     }
   }
}

onItemTap(args: ItemEventData) {
   if (args.ios) {
      args.ios.accessoryType = 3;
   }
}
```

I've tried looping over the current args but these args are specific to the item tapped not all the other items.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it to `None` (0) to remove accessory type.

```
onItemTap(args: ItemEventData) {
   if (args.ios) {
      args.ios.accessoryType = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: But this only sets the tapped item to none. What I want is to set the tapped item to 3 and if there is a previous one that was set to 3, set that to 0.

Comment: I hope this is what you are looking for - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=D8o4Nd

Comment: Thanks for code but still doesn't do what I need. Instead of being able to unselect items so the user could have no items selected) there always needs to have only 1 item selected. Essentially trying to replicate a radio button action with the accessory types.

Comment: It's pretty straight forward, use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to get previously chosen cell and toggle `accessoryType` - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=D8o4Nd&v=2

Comment: Oh cool. I didn't realise you could use iOS style syntax in NativeScript. Maybe some more reading is required. This works great. Thanks